# How to exclude the steps for Basic Settings authentication and Anonymous authentication while providing it in Wise Studio Package?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, windows-installer, wise

I am using Wise Studio Package 8, to create a virtual directory on IIS.

It creates the virtual directory, but I have to provide Basic Setting Authentication and Anonymous authentication. I am unable to find out in Wise Studio Package how can I set it.

I would also want to select the application pool from the installer.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create an installer, that creates an IIS virtual directory, and you want to change the authentication settings for this directory, from the installer ? Or something else ?

Comment: @cosmo0 I want to give the autehtciation settings from the installer